# "Some 40" vs "40 some" vs "40 odd"?

Tags: numbers

Are they all the same ? "Some 40" vs "40 some" vs "40 odd"

Syrian planes and helicopters have dropped barrel bombs on Islamic State-held areas in the north-east, killing **some 40** people, activists say.

Comment: At first, I could think about threesome, foursome but **never** 40some! :P

Comment: kicking off all ambiguities, I'd have used 'approximately/around'!

Answer (score 1):

The usage in:

> killing **some 40** people

is [***some***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/some) sense 7:

> *adverb*
>   7) approximately; about   ⇒ "some ten men"

*40 odd* might mean the same thing depending on context.

I can't think offhand of an example using *40 some*. There is *40 something*, meaning in the forties.

Comment: 40 odd = in the forties?

Comment: I usually hear some-odd combined, but that may be a Texas dialect thing. "Oh, I had 30-some-odd kids in my class" would mean a range from high 20s (27, 28, 29) to probably around the mid 30s (35, 36, 37).

Comment: "40-some" is a shortened form of "40-something" that people say where I'm from, which is the American Gulf Coast. Not sure where else it might be said.

Comment: Canada and we use a mix of both. Either the "30-some-odd" or "some-30" or "30-or-something".

Comment: Doesn't 40 odd have a slightly off hand connotation? It feels to me that saying that 40-odd people were killed would probably be regarded as insensitive.